# How to make scoreborad in tkinter

Tags: class, tkinter, pygame, tkinter-canvas

I would like to implement a scoreboard using a tkinter.
and i want make  if the distance between the object bullet and the object enemy is less than 10, I want to increase the score by 10.
How do I add code?
Thank you in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color, size, x, y, xspeed, yspeed):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xspeed = xspeed
        self.yspeed = yspeed
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+size, y+size, fill=color)

    def move(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.xspeed, self.yspeed)
        (x1, y1, x2, y2) = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        (self.x, self.y) = (x1, y1)
        if x1 <= 0 or x2 >= WIDTH:  
            self.xspeed = - self.xspeed
        if y1 <= 0 or y2 >= HEIGHT: 
            self.yspeed = - self.yspeed


bullets = []

def fire(event):
    bullets.append(Ball(canvas, "red", 10, 150, 250, 10, 0))

def up(event):
    spaceship.yspeed-=1
def down(event):
    spaceship.yspeed+=1


window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", fire)
window.bind("<Up>",up)
window.bind("<Down>",down) 


spaceship = Ball(canvas, "green", 100, 100, 200, 0, 0)
enemy = Ball(canvas, "red", 100, 500, 200, 5, 0)


while True:
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.move()
        if (bullet.x+bullet.size) >= WIDTH: 
            canvas.delete(bullet.id)
            bullets.remove(bullet)
    enemy.move()
    spaceship.move()
    window.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
```

Comment: Why have you tagged your question with 'pygame' since you don't use it in the code? You should also add the 'python' tag. In addition, I don't see any attempt in your code to implement a scoreboard. You will receive more help if you show us what you did and tell us where you are stuck instead of asking people to write the code for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to improve your program but I will concentrate on the collision aspect only.

Tkinter canvas has several methods; `find_closest`, `find_enclosed` and `find_overlapping` ([See here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#canvas.Canvas.find_overlapping-method.)) to allow you to detect where objects are in relation to each other. `find_closest` would be my first choice.

`find_closest` should take the x, y coordinates of the 'enemy' and a 'halo distance' (your less than 10 pixels). This will return the id's of objects nearby. If one of those objects is a bullet, then add 10 points to the score.

Some other things to fix/work on

- You don't have a tkinter.mainloop. You should
- Your method for moving the spaceship by changing the speed rather than the xy coords is poor and ends up with a very fast moving spaceship.